# Opportunity associated to OpptunityLîneItem

Tags: soql

I want to display All Opportunities associated with the same Product as this OpportunityLineItem

Comment: M’y visualforce page is on OpportunityLineItem object

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please review the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and see how to ask questions here.